# Having trouble requesting input in python

Tags: python, input, try-catch, handle, except

i have troubling handling input in python. I have a program that request from the user the number of recommendations to be calculated.He can enter any positive integer and blank(""). I tried using the "try: , except: " commands,but then i leave out the possibility of blank input. By the way blank means  that the recommendations are going to be 10.

I tried using the ascii module,but my program ends up being completely confusing. I would be glad if anyone could get me on the idea or give me an example of how to handle this matter.

My program for this input is :

```
while input_ok==False:                                                            
    try:                                                                          
        print "Enter the number of the recommendations you want to be displayed.\
        You can leave blank for the default number of recommendations(10)",          
        number_of_recs=input()                                                    
        input_ok=True                                                             
    except:                                                                       
        input_ok=False
```

P.S. Just to make sure thenumber_of_recs , can either be positive integer or blank. Letters and negative numbers should be ignored cause they create errors or infinite loops in the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    print ("Enter the number of the recommendations you want to " + 
            "be displayed. You can leave blank for the " + 
            "default number of recommendations(10)"),
    number_of_recs = 10 # we set the default value
    user_input = raw_input()
    if user_input.strip() == '':
        break # we leave default value as it is
    try:
        # we try to convert string from user to int
        # if it fails, ValueError occurs:
        number_of_recs = int(user_input)

        # *we* raise error 'manually' if we don't like value:
        if number_of_recs < 0:
            raise ValueError 
        else:
            break # if value was OK, we break out of the loop
    except ValueError:
        print "You must enter a positive integer"
        continue

print number_of_recs
```